# How do I split a string with fixed length columns & replace numbers in it with decimal numbers

Tags: python, string, split

Example, following is a fixed length string,

```
AB123.XY2020102310012USD
```

Following are the fixed length columns to be extracted,

Column1 = 2 (string)

Column2 = 6 (string)

Column3 = 8 (integer)

Column4 = 5 (decimal, 3.2)

Column5 = 3 (string)

**Output should be:**

```
Column1 = "AB"

Columns2 = "123.XY"

Column3 = 20201023

Column4 = 100.12

Column5 = "USD"
```

**Notice the decimal (.) in Column4 output**

I am able get the columns using following regex but not the decimal in 4th column,

```
re.compile("{}".format("(.{2})(.{6})(.{8})(.{5})(.{3})"))
```

Comment: Create 2 capturing groups `(\d{3})(\d{2})` instead of `(.{5})` and then add the dot between the two groups. The dot matches any char except a newline. You could also make the pattern a bit more specific by using for example `[A-Z]` or `\w`

Comment: Are you sure it's fixed length? Are the USD amounts always abc.xy? No prices of say thousands of dollars, or less then 100?

Answer (score 0):

The dot was not in the original string, and a regex can not pull it from thin air. Maybe you want to convert that number to a 3.2 format float number?

```
import re
line = 'AB123.XY2020102310012USD'

p = re.compile('(.{2})(.{6})(.{8})(.{5})(.{3})')
m = p.match(line)
float(m.group(4))/100 # this gives 100.12
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new string, which would bw

```
    oldString = AB123.XY2020102310012USD
    Column4 = oldString[:16] + '.' + oldString[16:]
```

This will create a new string with the . in the right place, from then you can just slice it as you please

Answer (score 0):

```
string = 'AB123.XY2020102310012USD'

Column1 = string[:2]

Column2 = string[2:8]

Column3 = int(string[8:16])

Column4 = float(string[16:21])/100

Column5 = string[-3:]

print(Column1)
print(Column2)
print(Column3)
print(Column4)
print(Column5)
```

OUTPUT

```
'AB'
'123.XY'
20201023
100.12
'USD'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is indeed fixed columns (which somewhere means a whole dataset), you may want to give it a try using pandas :

[pandas.read_fwf(filepath_or_buffer, colspecs='infer', widths=None, infer_nrows=100, **kwds)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

From the doc :

Read a table of fixed-width formatted lines into DataFrame.

**colspecs :** A list of tuples giving the extents of the fixed-width fields of each line as half-open intervals (i.e., [from, to[ ). String value ‘infer’ can be used to instruct the parser to try detecting the column specifications from the first 100 rows of the data which are not being skipped via skiprows (default=’infer’).